# optparse args gets nothing (python)

Tags: python, args, optparse

I saw this page: http://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html

wrote this code:

```
parser = optparse.OptionParser(usage=use)
parser.add_option("-z", dest="zipname")
parser.add_option("-d", dest="dictionary")

(options, args) = parser.parse_args()
print len(args)
```

so I tried it with:

> script.py -z hello.zip -d world.txt

and got:

> >> 0

when I use **options.zipname** or **options.dictionary** it's alright but nothing goes into args, why? thanks.

Comment: Note: optparse is considered depreciated. You should probably try using [argparse](http://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#module-argparse) instead. (I also personally like using [docparse](https://github.com/docopt/docopt), but it's not a part of the standard library)

Comment: @Michael0x2a deprecated != depreciated... Just sayin'..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `args` return value of `parse_args` is the "the leftover positional arguments after all options have been processed" (http://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html#parsing-arguments).  It parsed all the arguments you gave it, so there is nothing left to put in args.

If you run, for example,

```
script.py -z hello.zip -d world.txt foo bar
```

then `2` will be printed.

P.S. As @Michael0x2a pointed out in a comment, the `optparse` library is deprecated.  Take a look at the [argparse](http://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html) library.

Answer (score 0):

Because `args` are the leftover args after processing. From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html):

> parse_args() returns two values:
>
> - options, an object containing values for all of your options—e.g. if
>     --file takes a single string argument, then options.file will be the filename supplied by the user, or None if the user did not supply that option
> - args, the list of positional arguments leftover after parsing
>     options